# Error on array iteration calculation when number is high (result=0). But if number is low, the result correct

Tags: c

I make an array iteration to calculate the nearest round number to millions. For example, if input 3400000, the result is 3000000 which is correct. But if the input was 23200000 (desired result was 23000000), the result unexpectedly become 0.0000

The code I used:

```
main()
{
    double initial_num;
    double progress_num[10];
    double final_number;
    double difference;
    int i;  

    printf("input number : "); scanf("%lf",&initial_num);

    /*limit_awal=5802000;*/

    progress_num[0]=initial_num;
    for (i=1; progress_num[i]>0; i++) {
        progress_num[i]=initial_num-(i)*1000000;

        if (progress_num[i]<1000000) {
            difference = progress_num[i];
            final_number=initial_num-difference;
            break;
        }
    } 

    printf("Final number after rounding to million = %lf\n",final_number);
}
```

Comment: Probably your values are exceeding the bounds of datatype try a larger datatype ie int-> unsigned int -> long

Comment: I have tried resize the array and change datatype to double, etc. But fails. The result become 0.0000

Comment: since it has a multiplication there might me a case where in one of the value becomes 0 hence whole result is going 0. try to display all the variables value in every iteration in all the stages of logic u might find flaw in the logic or mistake which is causing the 0

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  1) the `main()` function only has two valid prototypes: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`   Notice that both prototypes have `int` as a return type.   2) the necessary `#include` statements for the needed header file(s) are missing.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.

Comment: OT:  regarding:  `printf("input number : "); scanf("%lf",&initial_num);`  For ease of readability and understanding, please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: OT: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of function, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  Those functions return the number of successful input format specifiers.  in this case: `scanf("%lf",&initial_num)` any value other than 1 indicates an error occurred

Comment: user2629249 - great input for me. I know these are kind of input from expert C. Even I dont fully understand it by now. I'll try to remember and apply those. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line

```
 for (i=1; progress_num[i]>0; i++) {
```

the code does not compare to the previous value, but to the current, which isn't even set.

Change it to be

```
 for (i=1; progress_num[i-1]>0; i++) {
```

Also adjust the array `progress_num`'s size, or add a test to not write beyond its bounds.

As well take care `i * 1000000` does not overflow `int`.

BTW: In C it has to be `int main(void)` at least.

Comment: Wow. I did not notice the [i-1] in progress_num.. But it actually solves the problem. Thank you!! God bless u alk......